# Drawing Recorder

Tags: web-apps, screen-recording, drawing

I am looking for a drawing recorder, ideally working embedded in the browser. I'm working on a web application, part of which will allow users to be able to load a background image, draw on top of it while recording and play it again some other time.

I found some possibilities on the internet like [this HTML5 based recorder](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/record-and-playback-drawing-in-html5-canvas-part-ii/), [the MIT Scratch Project has also some Drawing Recorder implementation](http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/342446/) or even a solution with [Camtasia, a desktop application](http://www.techsmith.com/tutorial-camtasia-draw-on-the-screen-prior.html).

I currently use a home-made Flash based solution (similar to Scratch) but I run into troubles when dealing with long drawings. I need it to run smoothly for recording even for 10 to 30 minutes recording (the current colution works fine but glitches for long drawing).

That's why I started to look for a well established and solid solution. Before I begin a very long and tedious benchmarking session for every alternatives I found, I was wondering if anyone has had similar requirements and/or knows a product that would be a good fit for me!